# .Net NetworkStream .Length not implemented how to know how much data available on stream

Tags: stream, packet, networkstream, packets

Since `NetworkStream.Length` was never implemented how else could I see how much data is already available on the networkstream.

Note I can't simply just `Read()` while `DataAvailable=True` I use a thread where it keeps running a function while `DataAvailable` is set, then this function should cut that batch off.

Here is my broken function just to show what I'm trying to achieve.

All my packets are sent with `[2 Bytes Size][1 Byte Type][Optional Payload]`

```
Public Function readPacket() As PacketReader
    'This cuts the stream of bytes into readable packets.
    Try
        If serverStream.DataAvailable Then
            If packetSize = 0 Then
                packetSize = serverReader.ReadUInt16()
                packetType = serverReader.ReadByte()
            End If

            If packetSize = 0 Then
                Return New PacketReader(packetType, New MemoryStream())
            End If

            If serverStream.Length >= packetSize Then
                Dim packet() As Byte = serverReader.ReadBytes(packetSize)
                Dim stream As Stream = New MemoryStream(packet)
                Dim tmpPacketSize As UShort = packetSize
                packetSize = 0
                Return New PacketReader(packetType, tmpPacketSize, stream)
            End If
        End If
    Catch e As Exception
        formLobby.logMsg("Exception: " + e.ToString)
    End Try
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it turns out. 
You cannot use the `NetworkStream.Length` function.
You need to use `TcpClient.Length` instead.

which contains the `NetworkStream`

aka

`TcpClient.GetStream()` returns `NetworkStream`